# Why is my modulo operation giving me bogus values?

Tags: c, modulus

When I run this code, I get outputs that don't really make any sense. I'm most likely just missing something, but I've been working on trying to find the problem with my code by working out the problems by hand, but I'm getting the values I should be getting when I do it by hand. A simplified version of this calculation is (c%10^n - c%10^(n-1)) / 10^(n-1).

The goal of this calculation is to assign the digits of a number to an array of ints. I'm not really looking for alternate solutions.

```
int cNumberV[nLength];
for(int n = nLength; n > 0; n--) {
    cNumberV[nLength - n] = (cNumber % (long long) pow(10, n) - cNumber % (long long) pow(10, n - 1)) / (long long) pow(10, n - 1);
    printf("%i\n", cNumberV[n]);
}
```

This is my output when cNumber = 5105105105105100 and nLength = 16:

```
-1981492631
232830
-1530494976
1188624
-397102900
134514540
-1081801416
1188624
0
1
5
0
1
5
0
1
```

Comment: `pow` is a floating point operation, and casting its result to an integer type throws away the fractional part. Essentially, you may get a `% 9` operation where you expected `% 9.999999`.

Comment: @quantdev complaining about using `pow` (a floating point function) is valid here, although I think that for IEEE754 this is always exactly representable so it should work

Comment: Why *not looking for alternate solutions"? This solution is dreadful, even if were working. Getting the digits of an integer requires only a single integer divide-by-10 inside the loop (assuming your compiler is smart enough to optimize a / and a % into one division).

Comment: @Jongware There should be no fractional parts to the modulo operation, unless pow loses accuracy at a certain point, right? nLength should never be greater than 16, so this should not be a problem.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I'm using this as a learning experience and I'm using ints, so the fractional components may not round correctly, correct?

Comment: Integer division will give you the correct integer quotient and remainder. You'll need a length of 20 to account for all possible `long long int` values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your loop sets `cNumberV[nLength - n]`, but then prints out `cNumberV[n]`.

So the first half of the loop prints uninitialized array entries, and the second half of the loop prints the result of the first half's calculation in reverse order (but due to an off-by-one error as pointed out by rowan.G, it never prints the first digit).

Comment: Ahh, thank you! When I loop through the array afterwards, I get values that make sense. My error was in logic - I'm not going to beat myself up over it though, I'll just use this as a learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

`pow()` is an expensive and inaccurate floating function. You only
need simple integer divide by ten to get digits. If you really want
to get them left-to-right as you do above, make a lookup table with
the 19 powers of 10 as integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define nLength 20

long long cNumber = 5105105105105100;
int cNumberV[nLength];
int negative = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (cNumber < 0) {
        negative = 1;
        cNumber = -cNumber;
    }

    int n;
    for (n = nLength - 1; n >= 0; n -= 1) {
        cNumberV[n] = cNumber % 10;
        cNumber /= 10;

        if (0 == cNumber) break;
    }

    if (negative) printf("-");
    for (int i = n; i < nLength; i += 1) {
        printf("%1d", cNumberV[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I would agree that this is a more efficient solution, but my goal was to become more comfortable with modulo operations. I also need to conserve cNumber for future operations (although I could just make a cNumberTemp variable or something similar to store it for the operation). Could I put "&& cNumber != 0" in the for loop to remove the need for an if statement?

Comment: Thank you! I might use this solution, but I'm still learning some basic C, so I'm just ensuring there was no error in my current understanding of it. Thank you again!